# Take p an odd prime and $a$ an integer with order $d$ mod p, is it true that if $d$ is even, then $a^{\frac{d}{2}} \equiv -1\pmod p$

Tags: proof-verification, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Suppose $p$ is an odd prime number and that an integer $a$ has order $d\bmod p$, is it true that if $d$ is even, then $a^{\frac{d}{2}} \equiv -1\pmod p$.

I claim the answer is yes and show it with the following. Would appreciate if someone could verify my proof.

Let $d = 2k$ since $d$ is even for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So we have $a^{2k} \equiv 1\pmod p \implies (a^{k})^2 \equiv 1\pmod p$. We know, since $p$ is a prime, that the solutions to $x^2 \equiv 1\pmod p$ are $x \equiv \pm 1\pmod p$.

If $a^{k} \equiv 1\pmod p$, contradicts order being $2k$. So we have $a^{k} \equiv a^{\frac{d}{2}}\equiv -1\pmod p$ as required.

Comment: Looks good, and very clear.

Comment: Thanks! Wondering what's the Math Exchange etiquette for these kind of proof verification questions. I got a couple more and should I explicitly answer them myself below if they're correct or just leave it be?

Comment: You can in any case put the tag "proof-verification". Then if there are mistakes they will be explained in an answer, otherwise (like in this case) I am also unsure on the best practice

Comment: If you have another proof you would like checked, you can ask another question.  You shouldn't use comments to ask new questions, because then people won' be able to search for them.

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is an odd prime number, then by Fermat's little theorem, $a^{p-1} = 1 \mod p$. Therfore any integer $d$ such that $a^d = 1 \mod p$ must divide $p-1$. It follows by Fermat's Little Theorem that $a^{(p-1)/2} = ±1 \mod p$ as well. Again, if $a^d = 1 \mod p$, then $a^{d/2} = ±1 \mod p$. Suppose the order of $a \pmod p$,  $d$ is even. Is $a^{d/2} = -1 \pmod p$? This depends on weather $a$ is a quadratic residue, or a quadratic non-residue modulo $p$. If $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, then $a^{d/2} = 1 \pmod p$, implying that the answer to your question is false. However, if $a$ is a quadratic non-residue, then $a^{d/2} = -1 \pmod p$. In fact, the [Legendre Symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol), $(a | p)$ for some prime number $p$ is the same as $a^{(p-1)/2} \pmod p$.